# Can you help me debug this c++ program which is supposed to add a node at the end in circular single linked list and print the list?

Tags: c++

Can you help me debug this c++ program which is supposed to add a node at the end in circular single linked list and print the list?

```
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;

    Node(int x)
    {
        data = x;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

class Lfun
{
public:
    virtual void addLast(int x) = 0;
    virtual void display() = 0;
    virtual  ~Lfun(){};
};

class List :public Lfun{
private:
    Node* head;
    Node* curr;
public:
    List()
    {
        head = NULL;
        curr = NULL;
    }
    void addLast(int x)
    {
        Node *tmp = new Node(x);
        tmp->next = head;

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            curr = head;
            while (curr->next != NULL)
            {
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            curr->next = tmp;
        }
    }
    void display()
    {
        curr = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cout << curr->data << " ";
        }
    }
};


int main() 
{
    List* ll = new List();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << i;
        ll->addLast(i);
        ll->display();
    }
}
```

I have created a class 'Node' to create a node for the linked list and another class 'Lfun' to redefine all the functions in the child class ,that is 'List'.
The program is not giving any output, can you explain why that is happening and how I can fix that problem?

Comment: @Yunnosch - Yes, I have tried debugging using cout<<i ,but its not giving any output. I have tried debugging the code further but I am not able to find any problem in it.

Comment: Do you get any output if you flush and remove the instantiation? You do know what I man by "flush", don't you?

Comment: I hope you are aware that 1) virtually any kind of basic data container -- including single and doubly linked lists -- already exist in the C++ standard library, and 2) if you want to learn how to create your own data container, this (doing a C API with a bit of C++ syntactic suggar sprinkled on) is the wrong way to do it. A data container should not leak memory, should use standard functions (addLast -> push_back, display -> operator<<) etc. -- If you don't know what exactly I am talking about, *you should not write a data container class*. Learn to **use** the standard library *first*!

Comment: `Node* curr;` is your gravest mistake so far. A list conceptually does not have a persistent current element. Get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is this line in List:

```
tmp->next = head;
```

With that line, you ensure that the last Node's `next` will never be NULL, but  point back at head, giving you a circular list.

In your while-loop you loop until you find a next member that is NULL, but due to the above problem, this will loop forever.

Your `display` function is also broken, as it prints the first element 5 times without advancing `curr`. Another thing is that `curr` should really not be a member variable, but rather a local variable in functions where it is used.

Also note that in c++, you should use `nullptr`, not `NULL`

Comment: Interesting observation. Do you have an idea how to fix?

Comment: @Yunnosch Simply remove the line setting `tmp->next` to head. Without this line, the last element's next will be NULL, and `addLast` will work as intended.

Comment: Would that not spoil the idea of a circular list?